# heatmap generated from numpy array gives inaccurate results

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, matplotlib, heatmap

I am trying to generate a heatmap using bounding boxes coordinates to display the area where the detected object went to inside a room. To do that, I created a numpy array and used the coordinates to create a mask and increment by 1 for all the bounding boxes. After that, I used a min_max_scaler to normalize the numpy array and create a colormap with matplotlib.cm.

```
import cv2
import csv
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from matplotlib import cm
from sklearn import preprocessing

min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()

with open(filename, newline = '\n') as file:
            lines = csv.reader(file, delimiter = "\t")            
            lines_list = [x for x in lines]

im = np.zeros((1080,1920,3), np.uint8)      
heatmap = np.zeros_like(im[:,:,0]).astype(float)
        
for li in lines_list:
    if li[1] == "valid":
        heatmap[int(li[3]):int(li[5]),int(li[2]):int(li[4])] += 1
        
result = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(heatmap)        
        
newim = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(cm.Wistia(result)*255)) 
opencvImage = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(newim), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR) 
#gaussian blur added to smoothen the edges of the boxes
opencvImage = cv2.GaussianBlur(opencvImage,(11,11),cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)
```

All seems fine, but when I see the result of the colormap, some areas representing the maximum value of the np.array seem inaccurate. Since the object's is large enough, the areas with the highest value need to be somehow similar in size, but there are parts colored with the darkest shade that are less than 10% the size of the average bounding box. For example, in the picture below, the area is actually a wall, so in order for the object to have crossed that area that many times, it would have also been through the area on the right or on top (equally or more). I checked the bounding boxes and they are correct, so no problem from that part.

[image]

The file I read data from: https://gofile.io/d/QaIgE8

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks a lot !

Comment: The first thing I'd do would be to check the array that you use to generate the heat map. Print it out in full (or even export to a css) and look at the area that you've circled - are the actual numbers correct? Bounding boxes can sometimes...jump about a bit between frames of a video, so it might even be worth drawing the bounding boxes on the video and watching that so you can see this.

Comment: you need to make this issue reproducible for others. right now there's no way to help in debugging this.

Comment: @Pam Thanks for the suggestions ! I did draw the rectangle and watch the videos and there were no issues with the boxes themselves. As for the array, since the actual image is quite big, it's really hard to view it in a print. I will try similar methods tho.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Thanks for the comment. I will try to add a file with the data to reproduce this

Comment: @Wazaki, if you fix it, you can refine and answer your own question so that it's useful for others in future. And yes - I'd suggest exporting to csv and viewing in (ahem) excel or something for simplicity (in the old days, you could view it in memory on the computer!). You just need to make sure the issue is definitely the heat map and not your number generation.

Comment: @Pam I saved the numpy in a csv file, and although it's hard to look through the giant table, I could still observe that the number pattern is generally correct. the number on the extreme left and right of the array are smaller. Now I'm starting to wonder whether the heatmap is inverting the intensity of the colors (brighter --> higher value) or something like that

Comment: If you just save the array as an image (either convert to greyscale or just repeat the array for R, G and B channels, scaling everything to be between 0 and 255, int), then blacker areas will be lower numbers (white=255,255,255). That might help explain the heat map. Also, portrait/landscape: are these the right way round? You’ve no idea how often I confuse x and y! And I’d take off the Gaussian blur, at least to start with for simplicity.